# how to getback result from invokescript() Webbrowser

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

i am trying to extract data from webpage has many index 
`this.webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("__doPostBack", new object[] { "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvTickets", "Page$2" });`
these code is working and goto second page in webbrowser but when debugging it is not coming backto documentcompleted method.
how can i get the responsetext on the secodpage

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code sample. 
This method is called from a Console application - hence the thread execution and
add [STAThread] attribute to your main method if u r using console app.
documentCompleted will be called recursively till the condition fails.

```
protected override void StartScan( string url )
    {
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        int i = 1;
        Thread thread = new Thread( () =>
        {
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler documentCompleted = null;
            documentCompleted = async ( o, s ) =>
            {

                if ( i < 27 )
                {

                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    document.LoadHtml(browser.DocumentText);
                    List<Establishment> establishments = GetEstablishments(document).ToList();
                    SaveResults(establishments);
                    string var = i < 10 ? "0" + i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    browser.Navigate( string.Format( "javascript:__doPostBack('SchoolDirectoryWebPart1$ctl{0}','')", var ) );
                    i++;
                } else {
                    browser.Dispose();
                    Application.ExitThread();
                }
            };


            browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            browser.DocumentCompleted += documentCompleted;
        browser.Navigate( url );
            Application.Run();

        } );
        thread.SetApartmentState( ApartmentState.STA );
        thread.Start();
    }
```